# How to use parameters using MySQL and a TADOQuery instance?

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc, c++builder, ado

I have a `TADOConnection` pointing to a MySQL 8.0 instance. The connection is tested and it works. Following [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/ADOQuery_(C++)) example on how to use prepared statement, I'm having an error and I have no idea why.

The following code works fine, it will return `true` from the very last statement. No errors, no warnings.

```
AnsiString sqlQuery = "SELECT e.name FROM employee e WHERE e.id = 1;";

if (!_query->Connection->Connected) {
  try {
    _query->Connection->Connected = true;
  } catch (EADOError& e) {
    return false;
  }
}

_query->SQL->Clear();
_query->SQL->Add(sqlQuery);

_query->Prepared = true;

try {
  _query->Active = true;

  if (_query->RecordCount == 0) {
    return false;
  }
} catch (EADOError& e) {
  return false;
}

return true;
```

However, the following code fails executing `_query->SQL->Add(sqlQuery);` with [this error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/ado-error-reference?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

```
AnsiString sqlQuery = "SELECT e.name FROM employee e WHERE e.id = :id;";

if (!_query->Connection->Connected) {
  try {
    _query->Connection->Connected = true;
  } catch (EADOError& e) {
    return false;
  }
}

_query->SQL->Clear();
_query->SQL->Add(sqlQuery);   // <---- EOleException here

_query->Parameters->ParamByName("id")->Value = id;

_query->Prepared = true;

try {
  _query->Active = true;

  if (_query->RecordCount == 0) {
    return false;
  }
} catch (EADOError& e) {
  return false;
}

return true;
```

Everywhere I find examples, all of them use `:paramName` to specify parameters. What am I missing?

---

### Update 1

I have tried changing the code like this :

```
_query->SQL->Clear();

TParameter * param = _query->Parameters->AddParameter();
param->Name = "id";
param->Value = 1;

_query->SQL->Add(sqlQuery);  // <---- EOleException still here
```

Some forum post suggests to switch the Advanced Compiler option "Register Variables" to "None", but this is already the setting of my project, and the exception is still thrown.

---

### Update 2

I can ignore the error, and everything gets executed just fine, however it fails whenever I perform a step-by-step execution. Of course, I can still put a breakpoint *after*, and jump right over the faulty line, but it's still annoying and does not explain **why** there is this error there in the first place.

Comment: A quick glance only, but I think you should not have a ";" character after your parameter name in the SQL statement: ie..... WHERE e.id = :id;  should be......WHERE e.id = :id

Comment: Also I do wonder why you are using AnsiString rather than String for your SQL statement? I don't think this achieves anything useful at this point.

Comment: @RogerCigol I agree. However this is a maintenance project, an over decade old code base (currently compiled with Borland C++ 2007) and the original authors only used this type everywhere. This is what it is.

Comment: C++ 2007 !!! I am pretty sure that paramatised SQL statements weren't supported that far back....

Answer (score 0):

The exception is on setting the SQL string - which tells you that it's wrong.  As per @RogerCigol's comment, you should NOT have the `;` at the end of your SQL string.

Kudos to Roger for that.

If you want to access parameters, you MUST set the SQL string first, it will be parsed to identify the parameters.  The parameters will not exist until the string is parsed, or you manually create them (which is pointless as they would be recreated on parsing the string).

You can also access the parameters as an ordered index, and I have always been able to use `?` as an anonymous parameter with MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but removing the trailing semicolon `;` does not change anything. I also tested creating the parameters, first, and it did not change anything. In fact, the error seem to be pointless because I can just ignore it. So, creating parameters before, or accessing them after parsing the SQL does not change anything. In short, even if I can ignore the error, it still does not explain why it's happening, and how it can be removed at all.

Comment: The example shows using String, not AnsiString, and the property SQL is defined as TStrings - so I would expect it to want a String.  Given that it is an EOleException you might see if it is happy with a BSTR as well ...